# How to create npm package after compiling program from source?

Tags: npm, phantomjs, raspberry-pi3

I need to install phantomjs in a project, but the binaries that are available around are not for my computer architecture (armv8, Raspberry Pi 3).
I downloaded and compiled the phantomjs browser and now I just need to know how I can make a npm package for it, so that I can install it in a project folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was no need to create a package to install the binary in my project folder.

All that's needed is to add the bin folder containing the binary to the PATH environment variable, like:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/path/to/bin/folder
```

and to install it in the project folder:

```
cd project_folder
npm install
```